What happens when I issue ALTER TABLE on a VIEW in Azure Databricks
Instead of giving ALTER VIEW I mistakenly issued the command ALTER TABLE on a VIEW and it didn't complain.
What are the implications of running ALTER TABLE on a VIEW ?
ALTER TABLE schema.view_name OWNER TO `group`


You can determine this for yourself by examining the permissions on the view.
To show the permissions for a given principal:
SHOW GRANTS `group` ON schema.view_name;

To show ALL permissions on an object:
SHOW GRANTS ON schema.view_name;

Ref.: SHOW GRANTS
